# How can I get {% url logout %} to work in my Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

My Django app's site-wide urls.py file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('myApp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url (
        r'^accounts/register/$', 
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=extendedRegistrationForm),
    ),  
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('myApp.urls')),
)
```

I also have a urls.py specific to myApp but I have not shown that here because I don't think it's relevant.

In my template file, I have this:

```
{% url logout %}
```

It gives me this error:

```
'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.
```

When I change the template to:

```
{% url 'logout' %}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

How do I put a link to logout in my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include `django.contrib.auth`'s URLs in your `urls.py`, so there is no logout URL.

Try adding something like

```
url(r'^auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Comment: What are the analogous template tags for password-rest and register? Documentation seems weak in this regard.

Comment: Those are in django-registration, if the docs don't mention it then just look at the django-registration's `urls.py`

Answer (score 10):

Add a logout url like this:

```
url(r"^logout/$", "django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login",
    name="logout"),
```

The correct template syntax is:

```
{% url 'logout' %}
```

Comment: vote down, because of the following error: TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: Second argument shouldn't be a string.

Answer (score 2):

In django 3.0 `{% url 'admin:logout' %}` works perfect.